# Can Nifi insert data into uppercase table in postgesql?

Tags: etl, apache-nifi

I create a dataflow try to insert data into uppercase table in postgesql.

But it does not work.

Appreciate any help on this issue, I am new to Nifi.

[nifi dataflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1J74.png)

Here are my setting for QueryDatabaseTable and PutDatabaseRecord.

[nifi dataflow querydatabasetable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa3Ry.png)

[nifi dataflow putdatabaserecord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxFYG.png)

The error message show below.

`org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.db.TableNotFoundException: Table "ACPMA" not found, ensure the Catalog, Schema, and/or Table Names match those in the database exactly`

[nifi dataflow table is not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r12YZ.png)

Here is a uppercase table ACPMA in postgesql.

[nifi dataflow db table is exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L29Rk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the table name to `ACPMA` (without quotes) in PutDatabaseRecord.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works after name without quotes!Can find the table in postgesql!